# Managed multiple connections pools in rust

Tags: rust, traits, rust-tokio, tokio-postgres

I'm building an app using salvo web framework in rust. The app will have multiple types of db connections (postgres no tls, postgres with tls, redis no tls, redis with tls). This will be user defined from a config file. Each of the connection types can have N number of instances. Each of those instances will have its own pool and can be referenced by its name.

Here is what I'm thinking of implementing

```
use core::panic;
use std::collections::HashMap;

use bb8_postgres::PostgresConnectionManager;
use serde_json::Value;
use tokio_postgres::NoTls;

use bb8::Pool;

pub struct AnyConnection {
name: String,
details: HashMap<String, Value>,
secure: bool
}

impl AnyConnection {

pub fn new(name: String, details: HashMap<String, Value>, secure: bool) -> Self {
    return AnyConnection { name: name, details: details, secure: secure };
}
}


#[salvo::async_trait]
pub trait PostgresPool {
    async fn make_unsecure(&self) -> Option<Pool<PostgresConnectionManager<NoTls>>>;
}

#[salvo::async_trait]
impl PostgresPool for AnyConnection {
    async fn make_unsecure(&self) -> Option<Pool<PostgresConnectionManager<NoTls>

 >> {

    let manager = PostgresConnectionManager::new_from_stringlike(
        &self.details.get("DATABASE_URL").unwrap().to_string(),
        tokio_postgres::NoTls,
    );

    let conn = match manager {
        Ok(m) => m,
        Err(err) => panic!("Error opening a connection for: {} with error: {:?}", &self.name, err.to_string())
    };        


    let pool = match Pool::builder().max_size(5).build(conn).await {
        Ok(p) => p,
        Err(err) => panic!("Error creating pool for: {} with error: {:?}", &self.name, err.to_string())
    };

    return Some(pool);
}
```

}

Here is how I'm initializing the pool in main.rs

```
let mut conns: HashMap<String, AnyConnection> = HashMap::new();

let mut details: HashMap<String, Value> = HashMap::new();

details.insert("DATABASE_URL".to_string(), Value::String("postgresql://localhost:5432/customers?user=postgres&password=postgres".to_string()));


let customers_db: AnyConnection = AnyConnection::new("customers_db".to_string(), details, false);        

let pg = PostgresPool::make_unsecure(&customers_db).await;
```

Where do I cache/store the `conns` HashMap which keeps the reference of connection pool objects? Are the connections "safely" returns to the pool that is stored in HashMap ?

UPDATE:

Based on the answer, I re-wrote the handle to this

```
#[async_trait]
impl Handler for HandlerWithPool {
    async fn handle(&self, req: &mut Request, _depot: &mut Depot, res: &mut Response, _ctrl: &mut FlowCtrl) {
        
        let delay: Option<u64> = req.query::<u64>("delay");

        // self.db_pools is available here
        let db_pools =  self.get_pools();
        let pgpool = db_pools.get("pg").unwrap();        

        let pgconn = match pgpool {
            AnyConn::Postgres(p) => {
                println!("Pool State: {:?}", p.state()); // shows more then 1 connection
                Some(p)
            },
            _ => None
        };

        let rows = pgconn.unwrap().get().await.unwrap().query("select * from users where id = $1", &[&"User-123"]).await.unwrap();        
        for row in rows {
            //println!("Row {:?}", row);
            
        }

        let dur = time::Duration::from_millis(delay.unwrap() * 1000);
        thread::sleep(dur);


        // Now you can do watever you need to with db_pool
        res.render("Hello World!");

    }
```

To test out the concurrency of the connection pools, I added a delay query parameter. Using that, I create my first request with delay 10 seconds and second with delay 1 seconds. It seems that second request does not complete until the first request is completed.

So it seems that it is locking the connection pool somewhere which is blocking the second request from fetching connections until first request returns it.

@harmic to answer your other question, I do not need to create pools  dynamically. All the pools will be set at server start.

Comment: Taking a peek at Salvo, it appears there's no mechanism to supply shared state to your handlers (which is the preferred way in other web frameworks), their examples use global variables (like [this one](https://github.com/salvo-rs/salvo/blob/main/examples/db-postgres-sqlx/src/main.rs#L6C1-L11C2)). Hopefully you wouldn't need a `Mutex` with your pool types since that would probably hinder concurrency significantly.

Comment: That being said, using a hash-map that is ultimately used to express values of differing types sounds un-ideal unless you *really* want to put the work into making the abstractions to treat a redis connection pool and postgres connection pool the same.

Comment: Probably not the end of the world, but you really shouldn't [repost questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77044905/named-connection-pool-in-rust)...

Comment: that question was closed so I figured I would re-write it. Deleted.

Comment: I would have N number of connection pools, so the example from salvo may not work as I have to define that upfront unless I'm missing something

Comment: @ed1t *technically* you should have edited that one with the material from this one, deleted this, and waited for that one to be reopened by 3 community votes. But I can't really say I blame you for going the way you did lol

Comment: Can you provide an example how you would *like* to use these pools? I'm a bit confused what the goal actually is. In my first comment, I linked to how Salvo demonstrates using connection pools (via static variables). Did that not help? Or are you confused how you would store `pg` within `conns` itself? I recommend against it (and have separate statics for each pool type), but I just want to understand what you're after.

Comment: Problem is I don't have a set number of connection pools, its dynamic and driven off a config files provided at the server start. So I have to store and retrieve it from dynamic structure rather then something pre-defined. If I need to pre-define something then it has to be flexible to support N number of connection pools for different types.

Comment: @ed1t the reason your edited version is blocking could be because you are calling `thread::Sleep` which blocks the whole thread. Try using [tokio::time::sleep](https://docs.rs/tokio/1.32.0/tokio/time/fn.sleep.html) instead, and await the returned future.

Comment: Tokio time sleep did the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Caveat Emptor: I have not used Salvo in anger, this answer is written based on their documentation.

> Where do I cache/store the conns HashMap which keeps the reference of connection pool objects?

So you have a data structure containing some resources, which you create in your main function, and you need to access within your handler functions.

To do this, you can create a struct which will house the connection pool objects and implement `Handler` for it, as described in the [Salvo documentation](https://salvo.rs/book/core/handler.html#implement-handler-trait-directly).

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;

use salvo::prelude::*;

struct AnyConnection;

struct HandlerWithPool {
    db_pools: HashMap<String, AnyConnection>,
}

#[async_trait]
impl Handler for HandlerWithPool {
    async fn handle(&self, _req: &mut Request, _depot: &mut Depot, res: &mut Response, _ctrl: &mut FlowCtrl) {

        // self.db_pools is available here
        let db_pool = self.db_pools.get("my_pool").unwrap();

        // Now you can do watever you need to with db_pool
        res.write_body("Hello World").unwrap();

    }
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    tracing_subscriber::fmt().init();

    let db_pools = HashMap::new();
    // Populate db_pools here

    let hello_handler = HandlerWithPool { db_pools };

    let router = Router::new().get(hello_handler);
    let acceptor = TcpListener::new("127.0.0.1:5800").bind().await;
    Server::new(acceptor).serve(router).await;
}
```

Your question does not make it clear what the expected usage pattern of the HashMap (which I have called `db_pools`) will be. I am assuming that you will read your config file on startup and then initialize it accordingly, with one or more [`bb8::Pool`](https://docs.rs/bb8/0.8.1/bb8/struct.Pool.html) structs.

Note that inside the `handler` method you have immutable access to `&self`, which means you can't update the `db_pools` HashMap. If your intended usage is to create more pools dynamically inside the handler, you would need to wrap it in a [`Mutex`](https://docs.rs/tokio/1.32.0/tokio/sync/struct.Mutex.html).

Instead of the rather complex trait & struct heirarchy you have proposed, I'd go with an enum to store the different types of pool, like this:

```rust
enum AnyConnection {
    Postgresql(bb8::Pool<PostgresConnectionManager>),
    Redis(bb8::Pool<RedisConnectionManager>),
}
```

> Are the connections "safely" returns to the pool that is stored in HashMap ?

Assuming you are using `bb8::Pool` instances to manage the connections, and you are talking about connections that you have obtained from the `Pool::get` method, then yes - you will get a reference to a database connection wrapped in a [`PooledConnection`](https://docs.rs/bb8/0.8.1/bb8/struct.PooledConnection.html), and when that goes out of scope the connection is returned to the pool, regardless of what owns the pool.